# Can I specify the response directly in Swagger 2.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am defining my response as per:

```
responses:
  200:
    description: 'An authProvider object'
    schema:
      type: 'array'
      items:
        $ref: '#/definitions/AuthProvider'
```

Is it possible for me to directly attach another field or 2 in the response? I would like to add something that I don't want to put into `AuthProvider`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever `$ref` is used, it's basically using [JSON Reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03). By definition (see linked spec), anything defined within the same object as the reference itself is ignored. As such, it is not possible to directly add additional properties alongside with the `$ref` definition.

That said, you *can* use composition to 'combine' two objects into one. This is done using the [`allOf`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor82) JSON Schema directive. A simple example for such a definition would look like this:

```
  allOf: 
    - 
      $ref: "..."
    - 
      properties: 
        property1: 
          type: "string"
        property2: 
          type: "boolean"
```

*Note 1*: The various Swagger tools out there may not fully support composition at the moment.
*Note 2*: As always, it's normally better to externalize the definition (even if used only once) rather than being defined inline.